# Acessing Firebase Child Value

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

I need to access Every Child after the UID:

[image: JSON]

[Json2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q1G0W.png)

I need to acess the +vvvv value. And put those values in my array for a tableView cell to load all values*.

Just need help how to gain these values when calling firebase.

For example:

```
+message_view
   +UID
      +value1
      +value2
      +value3
```

I need to access these values and put them into my tableView cell.

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let userID = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid

        if let userId = userID {
            ref.child("message_view").child(userId).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(snapshot) in

            let snapDict = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary




            //Assign array values
            self.messageDataArray.insert(postStruct(message: theValueIwant), at: 0)


            //self.tableView.reloadData()


        })
```

Comment: does these values have a key ? if so what is their key

Comment: what do you mean by key?

Comment: new to programming sorry.

Comment: Keys are absolutely critical to a relational database. It's the relationship between "parent" and "child" rows. Seriously, it's pretty much **the** basic concept of any database... without understanding it, you can't know (a) what a "primary key" is much less what your "vvvv" rows are. Sorry if this sounds cold - but it's very hard to be helpful here. Search on terms like "relational database", "primary keys", and "normalization". Given time, you'll glean the answer to this.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the values under your UID are strings, you could do as below. If they aren't strings, just change the type of the data array and cast to the correct type.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let userID = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid

    if let userId = userID {
        ref.child("message_view").child(userId)
           .observeSingleEvent(of: .value, 
                               with: {(snapshot) in
            var dataArray = [String]()
            for child in snapshot.children {
                let childSnapshot = child as! FIRDataSnapshot
                dataArray.append(child.value as! String)
            }

            //do anything with dataArray
        })
    }
}
```

Once the `for child in snapshot.children` loop is done running, you'll have all the children of your UID as an array and can do whatever you want with them.

Comment: thanks for the response. But i need to access all values* not just the vvvv with this work for that?

Comment: I dont need the values inside of vvv i need all values in +UID

Comment: OK, changed the code to access all values inside your UID. It's just a minor change.

Comment: It's important to know what is the type of the values under your UID. My code assumes the values to be strings, but you'll need to change this code in order to handle the actual values if they are not strings.